# How can I aggregate the columns with other data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a part of output from my joins in SP is like :

```
Col1 col2
A     1
B     1
C     2
C     1
```

I have another table that has all the possible values in `Col1 (A,B,C,D,E,F)` [The values are not known and as best practice I don't want to hardcode these values. ]

Expected output in SQL is as shown below

```
Col1   1            2
A     Yes        No/Null
B     Yes        No
C     Yes        Yes
D      No         No 
E      No         No
F      No         No
```

Appreciate the help I have relatively less experience in SQL and would appreciate if someone could help me understand how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `JOIN` with *conditional* aggregation :

```
with cte as (
     < query >
)
select c.col1, 
       max(case when t1.col2 = 1 then 'Yes' end),
       max(case when t1.col2 = 2 then 'Yes' end)
from cte c LEFT JOIN
     table t1
     on t1.col1 = c.col1
group by c.col1;
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh, this works. I hope someone else who is looking for a similar solution is helped by your response.

Answer (score 0):

Following [SQL pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) can be used if you can use '1/0' instead of 'YES/NO'

```
select
 *
from (
    select 
        letters.col1, mydata.col2
    from (
    select 'A' as col1 union all select 'B' union all select 'C' union all select 'D' union all select 'E' union all select 'F'
    ) letters
    left join (
        select 'A' as col1, 1 as col2 union all
        select 'B' as col1, 1 as col2 union all
        select 'C' as col1, 2 as col2 union all
        select 'C' as col1, 1 as col2
    ) mydata
        on mydata.col1 = letters.col1
) data
PIVOT (
 count( col2 )
 FOR col2
 IN (
  [1],[2]
 )
) PivotTable
```